# How negligible is a term in the internal energy for the equipartion theorem in classical mechanics?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, approximations

The equipartition theorem is a well-known result of classical statistical mechanics, and it states that if the Hamiltonian of a system can be written like this:
$$H=\sum_{j=1}^m {\alpha_j\ {x_j}^2}$$
where $x_j$ are $m$ independent real degrees of freedom of the system and $\alpha_j$ are arbitrary costants, then the internal energy $U$ is exactly
$$U=\frac{m}{2}k_BT$$
where $T$ is the temperature of the system ($k_BT/2\ $ for each degree of freedom).

Now, for example, in the case of a diatomic ideal gas composed of $N$ particles at temperature $T$, we usually say that, for every molecule, we have $3$ degrees of freedom associated to translation, and $2$ degrees of freedom for rotation, since the moment of inertia $I_n$ associated to axis aligned to the line connecting the two nuclei is negligible compared to the other $2$, meaning that the term in the Hamiltonian $I_n {\omega_n}^2/2\ $ can be neglected. So we have $5$ degrees of freedom for every molecule (ignoring elastic potential between the nuclei) and we conclude that the internal energy of the system is, classically speaking,  $U=5Nk_BT/2$.

My question is now, have we really the freedom of neglecting the term $I_n {\omega_n}^2/2\ $ in the Hamiltonian? I mean, the contribute to the internal energy that such term gives is $k_BT/2$, which is independent from the constant $\alpha_j$ (that in this example is proportional to the very small quantity $I_n$). If one decided, for some reason, to consider also this term, the internal energy would now be the result of a total of $6$ degrees of freedom per molecule, which would result in $U=3Nk_BT$.

So, in the case of this diatomic ideal gas, if one experimentally measures the temperature $T$, what is the total internal energy of the gas: $5Nk_BT/2$ or $3Nk_BT$? In the textbooks, the answer is the former, but why?

Of course, I'm making up this example only to prove my point, but my argument is more general, since in the process of demonstrating the equipartition theorem, one can see that the final result does not depend on the magnitude of the $\alpha_j$.